# How to use in array ? Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in

Tags: php, html, arrays

How can I deal with this error:

> Warning: `in_array()` expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\index.php

My code is:

```
if (!isset($_GET['jenis'])) {
  $jenis =  "";
} else {
  $jenis = $_GET['jenis'];
}


<li><input type="checkbox" onclick="jeniss();" name="jenis[]" value="11" <?php if (in_array("11",$jenis))  { echo "checked"; } ?> > <a> 11 </a> </li>
<li><input type="checkbox" onclick="jeniss();" name="jenis[]" value="12" <?php if (in_array("12",$jenis))  { echo "checked"; } ?> > <a> 12 </a> </li>
<li><input type="checkbox" onclick="jeniss();" name="jenis[]" value="13" <?php if (in_array("13",$jenis))  { echo "checked"; } ?> > <a> 13 </a> </li>
```

**Note:** the error at HTML input type when the page has not posted anything yet.

Comment: Well, `$jenis` is a string, so it's kind of hard to do an array search on it.

Comment: You could probably fix it by just changing `$jenis =  "";` to `$jenis =  [];`

Comment: @CD001 more simple, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check `$_GET['jenis']` is string or array by using

```
var_dump($_GET['jenis']);
```

if it is string than you have to define as a array just like that

```
$jenis = array($_GET['jenis']);
```

and you can use `in_array`

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter needs to be an array and you are passing the string instead of array.

It is like this  `in_array("value_you_wanna_look",$array)`

`$_GET['jenis']` is a string value not an array.

You may check against the value of $jenis like this

```
<?php if ($jenis=="11") echo "checked"; ?> // and so on for other values
```

**OR**

Enter the value in array like this:

```
$jenis = array($_GET['jenis']);
```

Answer (score 1):

As your error says, you are trying to pass string instead of array for `in_array()`. Please check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to have a better look at `in_array()`

According to your code

```
if (!isset($_GET['jenis'])) {
    $jenis =  array(); //<--- have empty array be default.
} else {
    $jenis = (array) $_GET['jenis']; //<---- change this line. You can typecast to array if you are getting only one value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `in_array()` you have to make sure that your second parameter is an array, you are providing a string as the second parameter.

Reason for this is that when `$jenis` is set by the form, it already is an array how you defined it, however before posting the form `$jenis` is not set and thus it will be set an empty string on line 2.

All you have to change is change line 2 to `$jenis = array();`.

Good practice is to make sure that a variable always has the same type or null. It will generally prevent these kind of mistakes (that might also become hard to test in complex cases).